# if controls in my android activity not working properly

Tags: java, android, if-statement

In my android project i.e in activity I used three if conditions and I checked three if conditions, but three 
conditions are actually true but control not entered into next (2nd and 3rd) statements.

code:

```
btnmangerphoto.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                countMngr=1;
                 RestaurentName=edtRestaurantName.getText().toString();

                 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                            android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                          startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
                         // ManagerPhoto="ok";
                        //new LongRunningedeleteonetimedeal().execute(); 
                          //count=1;
            }
        });

        btncomapnylogo.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 countLogo=2;
                RestaurentName=edtRestaurantName.getText().toString();
                 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                            android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                          startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

                         /* RestaurentName=edtRestaurantName.getText().toString();
                             NamePrefix=edtNamePrefix.getText().toString();
                            FirstName=edtFirstName.getText().toString();
                            LastName=edtLastName.getText().toString();
                            Telephone1=edtFirstNumber.getText().toString();

                            Telephone2=edtSecondNumber.getText().toString();
                            Telephone3=edtThirdNumber.getText().toString();


                            Email=edtEmail.getText().toString();

                            AddressLine1=edtAddressLine1.getText().toString();
                            AddressLine2=edtAddressLine2.getText().toString();
                            Speciality=edtSpeciality.getText().toString();

                            Cuisine = spinner.getSelectedItemsAsString();
        */
            }

        });

        //save Company Photos


        btnextraphotos.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                countCphoto=3;
                RestaurentName=edtRestaurantName.getText().toString();

                //Toast.makeText(ViewProvider.this, "imagecompanyphoto" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                            android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                          startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

            }
        });


    if(countCphoto==3){
                    cmpnayencodedString = Base64.encodeToString(byte_arr, 0);

                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("image",cmpnayencodedString));
                   Toast.makeText(ViewProvider.this, "cphoto=" +fileName  , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    new LongRunningSaveCompanyPhotos().execute(); 
                }


                if(countMngr==1){
                    mngrphotoencodedString= Base64.encodeToString(byte_arr, 0);
                    Toast.makeText(ViewProvider.this, "mangr" + fileName , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("image",mngrphotoencodedString));
                    //new LongRunningSaveCompanyPhotos().execute();
                    new LongRunningSaveManagerPhoto().execute();

                        }

                if(countLogo==2) {
                    logoFilename=fileName;
                    Toast.makeText(ViewProvider.this, "logo=" + logoFilename , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
```

Comment: Not clear what you're asking...

Comment: post your complete code your if statements are correct but where you are assigning values to countLogo ,countPhoto,countMmgr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible for the control to pass if your condition is false. Similarly if your condition is true, it has to go inside.

As per your statement, your first condition is passed which means countCphoto=3

But second condition and 3rd condition is not going in, it is evident that the conditions are false.

Can you Try a simple 
Toast.MakeText(.... 
with countMngr to see if it is really 1?

Also try the same with CountLogo just before the condition and let me know the values...

In one of the methods before this piece of code gets called there is a chance that this value is getting changed or re-initialize somehow.

Hope the above suggestion helps!

Answer (score 0):

I'm absolutely not sure, what your problem is, but as far as I understood that, you should give logging a try.

Just make a log statement in each if condition. 
e.g.

```
if (countLogo == 2) {
   Log.v("countLogo", String.valueOf(countLogo));
   logoFileName = fileName;
   // ...
}
```

Alternatively you can place that logging stuff above your if conditions